# View Reference Coordinate System

Tags: matrix

For a 3D scene in the World Coordinates, its View Reference Point is at c=(0,3,4), and
a viewer is looking towards its origin O (0,0,0). Construct a transform matrix which will
map World Coordinate points to a right-handed (UVN) viewing space, so that c is the
origin, the line joining c to O is the positive N axis, and the View-Up Vector is (0,0,1).

**My Attempt**

VRP = (0,3,4)

VUP = (0,0,1)

VPN = (0,0,0,) - c = (0,-3,-4)

n = VPN / |VPN| = (0,-0.6,-0.8)

**Stuck Here**

u = (n x VUP) / |(n x VUP)| =

I'm confused how we would solve u now?

After we have found u, I can just find v easy and then sub those values into the relevant matrices

Comment: This looks like a homework problem. Is this a homework problem?

Comment: @mHurley Question from an exam paper

Comment: What exactly don't you understand? You have n and you have VUP. And you have the formula for u. Just plug in the values. The x stands for the cross product which you can lookup if that makes you trouble. And the | | means length. / should be clear as division.

Comment: Should this be on Math.stackexchange ?

Comment: @ritwiksinha questions can be on topic on more than one site.

Comment: You have the answer, you have solved for u, after you have that n x u = v